# How to use workingDir and similar properties in a gradle method?

Tags: gradle

I have a task:

```
task buildDockerImageLocal(dependsOn: [build, copyDockerfile], type: Exec) {
    // ...
    workingDir "${buildDir}"
        // ....
}
```

But I need to move a lot of the code to a common method, because it is duplicated across similar tasks and no, making a pre-requisite task isn't a solution. So I just tried every single possible way I can think of, but nothing works. For example:

```
def buildDockerImage(task, String environment) {
    //......
    task.workingDir "${buildDir}"
    //......
}

task buildDockerImageLocal(dependsOn: [build, copyDockerfile], type: Exec) {
    buildDockerImage(this, 'local')
}
```

Will fail, with "Could not find method workingDir() for arguments"

What exactly is going on? In every single programming language I can move code to a method, what's up with Gradle that it fails? I think that Gradle is clearly doing something behind my back, but I have no idea what. I googled a lot, asked ChatGPT and still I can't understand why in Gradle I can't move some simple code to a standalone method...

thanks,

Comment: `workingDir` is a property of task type `Exec`, which your original task `buildDockerImageLocal` extends.  Once you're into a funciton like `def buildDockerImage(...)`, you're now in a Groovy function, not a task with properties.  Hence, deal with it as you would any piece of java/groovy code:  specify your path in your operations.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the "task" that I am at? It is clearly not a method body. And it doesn't look like a class definition either. I tried to define my own task class and use that, but it won't compile:

```abstract class DockerBuildTask extends Exec {
 workingDir = "${buildDir}"
 //......
 commandLine 'docker', 'build', //......
 doLast {
  println "Docker image created at ${buildDir}"
 }
}
task buildDockerImageLocal(dependsOn: [....], type: DockerBuildTask) {}```

Comment: Ok, I partially solved it: I need to create an abstract class DockerBuildTask extends Exec, but all the stuff need to go inside the constructor ... aff, gradle is so complicated.

But now, it still won't work because now I can't use ${buildDir} inside the constructor.....

Comment: When you write `def buildDockerImage(...)`, you are defining a method in Groovy.  Groovy is a JVM programming language, one of two that Gradle uses.  You can see method definition syntax [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_methods.htm).

Comment: It's the other way around, I'm not confused by Groovy methods. I don't understand why the task definition has access to stuff like ${buildDir} which I don't have access to in Groovy methods.

Comment: Groovy methods do have access to "$buildDir", but they don't have access to `workingDir`, which is a property/field of the `org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec` object.  Verified with:  `def printBuildDir() {println("Build Dir: $buildDir")}`, `tasks.register('ddd') {printBuildDir()}`, and then just running `./gradlew ddd`, which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to make it work. The key parts were:

1> Put the common code inside a new class which extends Exec so that I have access to stuff like "workingDir"

2> In this new class, put the code inside a custom method, so that I can pass variables unavailable for the custom class like ${buildDir} to it

```
abstract class DockerBuildTask extends Exec {
    def doAction(String buildDirParam, String env) {
//.....
        def buildDir = buildDirParam
        workingDir = "${buildDir}"
        //.....
    }
}

task buildDockerImageLocal(dependsOn: [build, copyDockerfile], type: DockerBuildTask) {
    doAction("${buildDir}", "local")
}
```